# Using lapply and str in R

Tags: r

When I input the following command in R.

```
lapply(list(1,TRUE),str)
```

It displays the following results:

```
num 1

 logi TRUE

[[1]]

NULL


[[2]]

NULL
```

I know `num 1` and `logi TRUE` are the structure of each element.
What is the meaning of the following part?

```
[[1]]

NULL


[[2]]

NULL
```

Comment: From `?str`: "str does not return anything, for efficiency reasons. The obvious side effect is output to the terminal.". So the first part is the side effect, the second is the result of it returning nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens because the return value of `str` is `NULL`. Consider:

```
a <- str(list(1,TRUE))
a # NULL
```

Now because you use `lapply`, lapply will return a list with an equal number of elements as the input list. In your case, this is a list of two elements that are both `NULL`.

Answer (score 0):

The `[[N]]` output means

1. The first element of this list is a vector with a single element `NULL`
2. the second element of this list is a vector with a single element `NULL`

Appending the `[[N]]` to the variable that holds the list actually returns the element.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the previous answers, it could be useful to use

```
invisible(lapply(list(dt1,dt2...), str))
```

so you don't print anything more than the structure of the objects.